# LINQ: several DeleteOnSubmit order behaviour on SubmitChanges

Tags: c#, linq

Using [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query), when calling several [deleteOnSubmit](http://theosmblog.com/2007/12/02/linq-and-c-part-2-deleting-records/) in a row then calling SubmitChanges:

```
DataContext.DeleteOnSubmit(itemFromTb1);
DataContext.DeleteOnSubmit(itemFromTb2);

DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Will they always be deleted in the order (*itemFromTb1 then itemFromTb2*) I called them or not necessarily?

**Edit:**
I know the SubmitChanges() performs in the following order

1. Insert
2. Update
3. Delete

But I'm not sure if each of those are performed in the order they were called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that nobody knows the official behaviour of SubmitChanges() in this case. I had a lot of "I think they are done in the same order" and did not find any article or offical info on it. 
It does not seem that many people had any problem with that so either everybody does a SubmitChanges() after each DeleteOnSubmit or we can rely on statistics :s to conclude that they are done in the order they were called.

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience they are deleted in the order in which you add them. You can verify this by examining the resulting SQL code that is generated, using the context Log property.

Comment: Even if they are in the right order in the sql it might not guarantee they will always be. I can't seem to find any info on the delete order it might mean it's in a "logical" order so there is nothing to say about it.

Comment: @DrDro - If you absolutely need to control the order, you'll probably have to do them one at a time, with a SubmitChanges() after each. If you need to do this within the scope of a transaction, you can use TransactionScope, which would wrap all SubmitChanges into a single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

We had a bug and that bug shows that they are not executed in order. Our case is the following:

```
       List<TabletFile> ofpList = (from tf in myDB.TabletFiles
                                         where tf.mimetype.Equals("xxx")
                                         select tf).ToList<TabletFile>();

        myDB.TabletFiles.InsertOnSubmit(tabletFile);

        if (ofpList.Count > 0)
        { 
            myDB.TabletFiles.DeleteOnSubmit(ofpList[0]);
        }
        myDB.SubmitChanges();
```

In this code sometimes insertion is executed firstly and sometimes delete.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the deletes are performed in order by table name.  [This page says:](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f718e275-be79-4b94-a400-a0705d411d73/deleteonsubmit-does-not-observe-the-order-between-parent-and-children?forum=linqtosql)

> Linq2Sql executes the SQL statements in the alphabetical order of the table names

Or if you believe [this page:](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27577/Cascading-Deletes-in-LINQ-to-SQL)

> The order in which the entities are marked for deletion does not matter, LINQ to SQL sorts that out during the execution of the Submit Changes call based upon the configuration of the foreign keys.

If the deletes are on the same table, they apparently are done in order of the statements but your mileage may vary.